# php code to get selected index id from listbox and get id on another page

Tags: php

table name ---   news

i created two pages 
1) sethomepage.php
2)exec_setpage.php

**I created a listbox and fill it from database on sethomepage.php**

**Now I need to pass id of selected value from listbox to exec_setpage.php**

below is my code

**plz suggest me how to get selected value index and GET on another page.**

bcoz it shows me error **undefined index id**

**sethomepage.php code**

```
<select id="news" name="news" size="20" style="width:400px; height:370px; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; float:left; overflow:auto"> 
        <?php                  
        foreach($news as $load_news)
        {                       
        ?>      
        <option value="<?php echo $load_news["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $load_news["headline"]; ?></option>
        <?php }?>       
        </select>

<td><a href="exec_setpage.php"></a></td>
```

**exec_setpage.php code**

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['Auth']['id']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
$errors = array();
$Admin = new admins;
if(isset($_POST['Add']))
    {   
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT id,status FROM news WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysql_query("Update news SET status='1' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
        {

            $_SESSION['message'] = "News Added Successfully";
            header("Location:sethomepage.php");
            exit;
        }
        else
            $_SESSION['message'] = "News Already Added Top List.";
            header("Location:sethomepage.php");
            exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Add `<form action='exec_setpage.php' method='POST'>` and also an `<input type='submit' name='add' />` and let the magic work.. BTW, you'll have to choose between `POST` and `GET` since you are mixing it up quite awefull in the second page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sethomepage.php code

```
<form action="exec_setpage.php" name="sel_news" method="post">
<select>
...
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

exec_setpage.php

```
$id = $_POST['sel_news'];        //Get the value of selected option
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="exec_setpage.php" name="sel_news" method="post">
<select id="news" name="news" size="20" style="width:400px; height:370px; border:1px solid  BBBBBB; float:left; overflow:auto"> 
    <?php                  
    foreach($news as $load_news)
    {                       
    ?>      
    <option value="<?php echo $load_news["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $load_news["headline"]; ?></option>
    <?php }?>       
    </select>

<input type="submit" name="submit">


 $id = $_POST['news'];
```